# How does symfony allow a var_dump() to display on the final page?

Tags: symfony

I have this code snippet from a symfonycasts video tutorial:

```
#[Route('/')]
public function homepage(): Response
{
    $tracks = [
        ['song' => 'Gangsta\'s Paradise', 'artist' => 'Coolio'],
        ['song' => 'Waterfalls', 'artist' => 'TLC'],
        ['song' => 'Creep', 'artist' => 'Radiohead'],
        ['song' => 'Kiss from a Rose', 'artist' => 'Seal'],
        ['song' => 'On Bended Knee', 'artist' => 'Boyz II Men'],
        ['song' => 'Fantasy', 'artist' => 'Mariah Carey'],
    ];

    var_dump($tracks);

    return $this->render('home/homepage.html.twig', [
        'Heyyyy' => 'Waaasssup',
        'tracks' => $tracks,
    ]);
}
```

I know that i should not use a var_dump but i wanted to try anyway and it actually displays the dump on the browser page but i don't get how...

I thought that the content of the final page would only be the content's value from the Response object that is returned by the render() method? So how can the var_dump content be displayed on the final page?

Am i missing something? Thanks.

I tried to understand... and it led to nothing!

Comment: what do you mean, you don't know how? `var_dump` prints stuff to the output. **The `Response` returned would not be able to set any headers** (which is why you shouldn't use `var_dump`), but beside that, the response would be printed anyway (after the output of `var_dump`). I mean, sure, theoretically symfony could start an output buffer to catch every output other than responses. But why would it? so technically, the output of `var_dump` is visible, because it creates output, don't know how else to explain it really ;oD Symfony is no magic, it's still plain php code that does stuff.

Answer (score 0):

@Jakumi is right, the PHP Interpreter will **prepend the dumped output** before anything else in the response content.

See the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for more information about `var_dump()`.
It also states, that you can control the output by using the `Output Control` of php. (see [PHP Output Control](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php))

Comment: `var_dump()` output does not receive any special treatment, and neither do any other methods that print to standard output (such as `echo`). Symfomy output comes last because, well, it's generated last.